# What is the best hosting solution for a classified site using Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, hosting

I am creating a website for classified using Wordpress. I was looking at hosting possibilities. I am a little worried about my choice, as with any classified website the big issue is with Storage of images and videos. Mainly, all sites are offering capped storage around 50Gb-100Gb. How do you usually go about this kind of situation, where you know the storage requirement will be more than 50Gb at a certain level of time? Do you just start and then when the day comes you move out? Should delete expired posts? Any insights will be more than welcome!

Yous

Comment: There is a dedicated WordPress stack exchange site that would be ideal for this question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't trust web hosts that offer unlimited bandwidth and storage.**

It costs them money and they're not going to give it to you for free.

If you have loads of static contents (mainly images), use a WordPress plugin that can throw it all to cheap offsite storage like Amazon S3. This way, you're paying minimal costs for this storage and using the 'regular' hosting for PHP (WordPress).

Also, you should use a caching plugin, like WP Super Cache, to drastically decrease the processing load from your server.

This way, you'll be making good use of resources, pay the minimal fee and get high performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose the right hosting provider they should be able to upgrade your server to fit your needs storage, clusters etc when needed your app grows. If you are going to have lots of data maybe think about setting up a storage farm and buying it cheap when you need it. i.e:

farm1.example.com
farm2.example.com

Add new farms as they get full.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend `hostgator.com` for hosting.
`Site5's` wordpress hosting is good too.

P.S:Don't even try `GoDaddy!` Had a real bas experience.

Answer (score -1):

You could go for a host that offers unlimited bandwidth and storage, like [Arvixe web hosting](http://www.arvixe.com/1080.html).

Comment: There is no such thing as unlimited bandwidth or unlimited storage.  If there was, every porn site in the world would host at that provider.